# Variable selection in causal inference regression models when $p > n$?

Tags: multiple-regression, feature-selection, causality, counterfactuals, backdoor-path

Are there accepted techniques for selecting variables in causal inference (not prediction) where the number of variables exceeds our sample size, making a standard OLS regression impossible?

Assume treatment, outcome, and covariate variables have been carefully selected with a causal diagram, based on subject area knowledge or information from prior randomized controlled trials.

That is, only variables which close back-door paths from the outcome to the treatment variables have been selected. There may also be moderators (such as age and gender) or risk factors having a close causal relationship with the outcome but not the treatment. Therefore, all of the selected variables are important in reducing bias or increasing precision of treatment effect estimates.

Comment: I may not understand the question. The do-calculus identifies valid adjustment sets for estimating a causal estimand. If none of the valid adjustment sets are compatible with doing OLS then don't use OLS.

Comment: @Galen The question is whether we can still obtain unbiased treatment effect estimates using regression when $p > n$ (eg, perhaps with a a variant of Lasso or ridge regression). I know Pearl's do-calculus doesn't make model recommendations - perhaps it's better to use a different technique (like propensity score matching) rather than regression in these cases?

Comment: Definitely fact check me on this as I am relying on second-hand knowledge, but I recall that do calculus is (1) universal in that it determines the full set of valid adjustment sets and (2) comes to equivalent conclusions about statistical control as the potential outcomes framework (whose practitioners often use propensity score matching).

Comment: When it comes to the statistical estimation with $p>n$ I would be tempted to go with a Bayesian inference. I would use [NUTS](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4246) as long as your likelihood is smooth, otherwise something valid but less efficient like Metropolis-Hastings. That removes the problem of degrees of freedom but gives you the problem of selecting justifiable priors.

Comment: @Galen Thanks, I'll read the NUTS paper, have not heard of that technique. Do you mean use Metropolis-Hastings to find best fitting regression models that minimize the likelihood (or AIC, BIC)?

Comment: You *could* do variable subset selection with Bayesian methods numerically with MH, but that isn't what I had in mind. Rather I was thinking about using the adjustment set you obtained from the do calculus to decide on what variables to use. See [Gelman *et al* 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01808) for a model development process. For model comparisons I recommend [WAIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watanabe%E2%80%93Akaike_information_criterion) over AIC. Not sure how WAIC compares to BIC.

Comment: I see there is a [WBIC](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume14/watanabe13a/watanabe13a.pdf), but I couldn't say how that compares with WAIC at the moment.

Comment: @Galen Cool thank you! Hmm curious if I generate a simulated dataset with say 200 confounders and $n$=150, could I do a "Metropolis-Hastings regression" that converges on minimum WAIC and an unbiased estimate of the true ATE (= treatment coefficient) despite having a singular matrix?